# Tidy up output of bash script that sends a series of commands to fdisk

Tags: bash

I've got a bash script that sends a series of commands to fdisk:

`printf 'n\np\n3\n\n\n\n\nt\n3\n8e\nw' | fdisk /dev/sda`

So, commands sent in order are: n, n, 3, [default], [default], t, 8e, w.

This works but what you see is very messy and hard to follow - there is no linebreak after an input so you see the next prompt from fdisk on the same line and it wraps around.

How could I re-do this so that there are appropriate line-breaks after each one?

Comment: why you dont write a function?

Comment: `function SendFdisk() { echo $@|sed 's/ /\\n/g' |fdisk /dev/sda ;}` Example usage : `SendFdisk n n 3 "" "" t 8e w`

Comment: This is probably something you should use the expect program for. It is designed to send and receive input from interactive tools. `man expect`. Commented because it's not a real answer, yes, I know. You can use pauses in it and check for each line of output (prompt) that you want. Alternatively, there might be a way to use fdisk with more options to reduce the need for interactivity at all, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: Just for readability purposes I usually script it like this: `(echo n; echo p; echo 3; echo; echo; echo 5; echo 8e; echo w) | fdisk /dev/sda`   Its not an ideal solution, but I find it clearer than the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Use input redirection:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda <<EOF
n
n
3


t
8e
w
EOF
```